# Why does bigint compile in one case and not in the other?

Tags: f#

I am just starting with F#, and I found the behavior displayed below puzzling. Any explanations?

```
let bg = bigint 1;;
(* val bg : System.Numerics.BigInteger = 1 *)

let bg = (bigint) 1;;
(* error FS0041: A unique overload for method 'BigInteger' could not be determined based on type information prior to this program point. A type annotation may be needed. Candidates: System.Numerics.BigInteger(value: byte []) : unit, System.Numerics.BigInteger(value: decimal) : unit, System.Numerics.BigInteger(value: float) : unit, System.Numerics.BigInteger(value: float32) : unit, System.Numerics.BigInteger(value: int) : unit, System.Numerics.BigInteger(value: int64) : unit, System.Numerics.BigInteger(value: uint32) : unit, System.Numerics.BigInteger(value: uint64) : unit *)
```

Comment: Why would you expect the second one to work?

Comment: Because the only difference from the first one is a parentheses. For example, both `let j = int "4";;` and `let k = (int) "4";;` work and have the same output `val j : int = 4`.

Comment: @Soldalma: 'int' is actually a function defined in the Core library, and uses some arcane inlining to find the correct type conversion, therefore it also works when using parentheses. See also https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp/blob/master/src/fsharp/FSharp.Core/prim-types.fs line 4262.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because of overloading. See, `bigint` is actually a synonym for the `BigInteger` class, and applying it like a function translates into calling a constructor, but which one of the several constructors depends on the type of the argument.

This works fine when you're applying it like a function: the type of the argument is known, and the compiler can select the appropriate overload. But if you're trying to treat it as a function-value, the argument is absent, and the compiler doesn't know which overload to take.

Here's a simpler repro:

```
type T() =
  member static f (s: string) = s
  member static f (i: int) = I

let a = T.f 1 // works
let b = T.f "abc" // works
let c = T.f // doesn't work: which `f` do you mean?

// possible workaround: create non-overloaded wrappers
let fStr (s: string) = T.f s
let fInt (i: int) = T.f i
let a = fStr // works fine
let b = fInt // works fine, too
```

Conclusion: overloading is bad, don't use it. But if you're stuck using it, just stuck it up. Or use a workaround.

---

#### On the role of parentheses

(in response to comment)

The parentheses tell the compiler: "*first thing, calculate this expression inside the parentheses, then take the result and do the rest with it*". So that putting a thing in parentheses is semantically equivalent to giving it a name, e.g.:

```
// Original repro:
let a = (bigint) 5

// Same thing:
let f = bigint
let a = f 5
```

Or another way to phrase the same idea: because the function argument is not present inside the parentheses, it cannot be used to evaluate the expression inside the parentheses; and because there is no argument, there is no way to resolve the overload.

Comment: You clearly pointed to the issue, but the role of the parentheses is still unclear. In both of the cases that don't work there are no parentheses. Why doesn't the parser/compiler just ignore or discard the parentheses?

Comment: Updated the answer.